# Show that: $\left[\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_1^{\infty } \frac{\sin (x)}{x^{\{n+1\}}} \, dx\right] = 0 $

Tags: integration, limits, taylor-expansion, pointwise-convergence

> Show that: $$\left[\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_1^{\infty }
>  \frac{\sin    (x)}{x^{\{n+1\}}} \, dx\right] = 0 $$

My attemp:
I using Taylor series:
$$
\sin(x)= x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+O(x^{11})
$$

$$\left[\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_1^{\infty }
 \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+O(x^{11})}{x^{\{n+1\}}} \, dx\right] = 0 $$
We have main part
$$
\left[\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\int_1^{\infty }
 \frac{1}{x^{\{n\}}} \, dx\right]  = \frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}
$$
But it's not convergence.

Do you have better a idea?

Comment: For $n > 1$ we have $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^n}\,dx = \left.\frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}\right|_1^\infty = \frac{1}{n-1} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$ so I'm not sure what you meant by "But it's not convergence".  It seems to converge just fine.

Comment: My mistake! Many thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use the Taylor series.  For $x > 0$, $$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{n+1}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$$ so that $$\left|\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{n+1}}\,dx\right| \leq \int_1^\infty \left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{n+1}}\right|\,dx \leq \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\,dx = \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

Answer (score 4):

We have on $[1,\infty)$: $$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{n+1}}\right| \le \frac{1}{x^2}$$ and $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx = 1 < \infty$$

So we can use dominated convergence theorem to get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{n+1}} dx = \int_1^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{n+1}} dx = \int_1^\infty 0 \;dx = 0$$